# What could be used to thicken Ferric Chloride solution?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm curious if it's possible to thicken Ferric Chloride so I can control it more on a less than horizontal surface ?

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but suggestions for you to test the thickeners (and surfactants) added to:

- Phosphoric acid-based [Naval Jelly® Rust Dissolver](https://www.loctiteproducts.com/en/products/specialty-products/surface-treatments/loctite_naval_jellyrustdissolver.html) (thixotropic polysaccharide, silicon dioxide) and
- This [HCl-based toilet cleaner formula](https://yeserchem.com/creating-a-powerful-toilet-bowl-cleaner-formula/) from Yeser suggests [polyoxyethylated oleyl amine](https://yeserchem.com/poe-2-oleyl-amine/)
- [Carbopol® 674 polymer](https://www.lubrizol.com/Home-Care/Product-Finder/Products-Data/Carbopol-674-polymer), a lightly crosslinked polyacrylic acid polymer.

Note that $\ce{FeCl3}$ solution, by itself, is not terribly stable, and the added thickener would likely react with it immediately, or catalytically slowly destroy it. Thus, this would be a good experiment to test, and to edit this answer, or at least comment on your results, to help others.

Comment: I have the Naval Jelly currently so I'll try that first and acquire the others ! Thank you

Comment: The other Naval Jelly ingredients might react badly with the FeCl3. The thing is to get the *thickener* in it, as with the others.